# Cannot deserialize XML object

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

Here is my XML string:

```
 <Surveys>
   <Survey>
      <SurveyID>33</SurveyID>
      <CulvertID>5</CulvertID>
      <PRNo>599422</PRNo>
      <MP>5.243</MP>
      <RefMiles>1.500</RefMiles>
      <PtID>ABCGEFGH</PtID>
      <FWVersion>10</FWVersion>
      <SurveyDate>2012-08-21</SurveyDate>
      <FutureComments>a33537e2-6c2a-4bde-ac99-4da82a93c598</FutureComments>
      <Erosions>
         <Erosion>
            <ID>158</ID>
            <SurveyID>33</SurveyID>
            <Location>Test Erosion - 8/21/2012 - 10:16:10 AM</Location>
         </Erosion>
         <Erosion>
            <ID>159</ID>
            <SurveyID>33</SurveyID>
            <Location>Test Erosion - 8/21/2012 - 10:16:10 AM</Location>
         </Erosion>
      </Erosions>
      <Spans>
         <Span>
            <ID>86</ID>
            <SurveyID>33</SurveyID>
            <Material>Test Span - 8/21/2012 - 10:16:10 AM</Material>
         </Span>
         <Span>
            <ID>87</ID>
            <SurveyID>33</SurveyID>
            <Material>Test Span - 8/21/2012 - 10:16:10 AM</Material>
         </Span>
      </Spans>
   </Survey>
   <Survey>
      <SurveyID>35</SurveyID>
      <CulvertID>5</CulvertID>
      <PRNo>587180</PRNo>
      <MP>5.243</MP>
      <RefMiles>1.500</RefMiles>
      <PtID>ABCGEFGH</PtID>
      <FWVersion>10</FWVersion>
      <SurveyDate>2012-08-27</SurveyDate>
      <FutureComments>7c36fe43-78cb-436e-81cf-f416aa63c8fc</FutureComments>
      <Erosions>
         <Erosion>
            <ID>160</ID>
            <SurveyID>35</SurveyID>
            <Location>Test Erosion - 8/27/2012 - 1:19:04 PM</Location>
         </Erosion>
         <Erosion>
            <ID>161</ID>
            <SurveyID>35</SurveyID>
            <Location>Test Erosion - 8/27/2012 - 1:19:04 PM</Location>
         </Erosion>
      </Erosions>
      <Spans>
         <Span>
            <ID>88</ID>
            <SurveyID>35</SurveyID>
            <Material>Test Span - 8/27/2012 - 1:19:04 PM</Material>
         </Span>
         <Span>
            <ID>89</ID>
            <SurveyID>35</SurveyID>
            <Material>Test Span - 8/27/2012 - 1:19:04 PM</Material>
         </Span>
      </Spans>
   </Survey>
</Surveys>
```

Here are my classes..

Survey:

```
namespace DNR.CulvertInventory.SERVICE
{
    [XmlRoot(Namespace="",
     ElementName = "Survey",
     DataType = "string",
     IsNullable = true)]
    public class Survey: BOBase
    {
        public int SurveyID { get; set; }
        public int CulvertID { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public string RoadName { get; set; }
        public int PRNo { get; set; }
        public decimal MP { get; set; }
        public decimal RefMiles { get; set; }
        public string PtID { get; set; }
        public short FWVersion { get; set; }
        public double? Latitude { get; set; }
        public double? Longitude { get; set; }
        public string Waterway { get; set; }
        public string SiteID { get; set; }
        public string Observers { get; set; }
        public DateTime SurveyDate { get; set; }
        public string AdjacentLandowner { get; set; }
        public string LocationComments { get; set; }
        public short? CrossingType { get; set; }
        public string StructureShape { get; set; }
        public string InletStructure { get; set; }
        public string OutletStructure { get; set; }
        public string OutletType { get; set; }
        public string SubstrateInStructure { get; set; }
        public string GeneralCondition { get; set; }
        public short? PluggedPercent { get; set; }
        public string PluggedLocation { get; set; }
        public short? CrushedPercent { get; set; }
        public string CrushedLocation { get; set; }
        public bool? IsRustedThrough { get; set; }
        public string StructureInterior { get; set; }
        public decimal? StructureWaterDepthInlet { get; set; }
        public decimal? StructureWaterDepthOutlet { get; set; }
        public decimal? StructureEmbeddedDepthInlet { get; set; }
        public decimal? StructureEmbeddedDepthOutlet { get; set; }
        public decimal? StructureWaterVelocityInlet { get; set; }
        public decimal? StructureWaterVelocityOutlet { get; set; }
        public decimal? StructureWaterVelocityMeasured { get; set; }
        public string StructureWaterVelocityMeasuredWith { get; set; }
        public bool? IsPerched { get; set; }
        public decimal? PerchHeight { get; set; }
        public string StreamFlow { get; set; }
        public bool? IsScourPoolPresent { get; set; }
        public decimal? ScourPoolLength { get; set; }
        public decimal? ScourPoolWidth { get; set; }
        public decimal? ScourPoolDepth { get; set; }
        public bool? IsUpstreamPondPresent { get; set; }
        public decimal? UpstreamPondLength { get; set; }
        public decimal? UpstreamPondWidth { get; set; }
        public decimal? RiffleWaterDepth { get; set; }
        public decimal? RiffleBankfullWidth { get; set; }
        public decimal? RiffleWettedWidth { get; set; }
        public decimal? RiffleWaterVelocity { get; set; }
        public string RiffleMeasuredWith { get; set; }
        public string RiffleSubstrate { get; set; }
        public string RoadSurface { get; set; }
        public string RoadCondition { get; set; }
        public decimal? RoadWidth { get; set; }
        public string LocationOfLowPoint { get; set; }
        public string RunOffPath { get; set; }
        public decimal? FillDepthUpStream { get; set; }
        public decimal? FillDepthDownStream { get; set; }
        public string SlopeUpStream { get; set; }
        public string SlopeDownStream { get; set; }
        public decimal? ApproachLengthLeft { get; set; }
        public decimal? ApproachLengthRight { get; set; }
        public string ApproachSlopeLeft { get; set; }
        public string ApproachSlopeRight { get; set; }
        public string VegetationDitchLeft { get; set; }
        public string VegetationDitchRight { get; set; }
        public bool? IsErosionPresent { get; set; }
        public bool? IsErosionCorrectable { get; set; }
        public string ErosionExtent { get; set; }
        public string ErosionNotes { get; set; }
        public bool? IsPrioritySite { get; set; }
        public string PriorityReason { get; set; }
        public string PriorityComments { get; set; }
        public bool? FutureVisit { get; set; }
        public string FutureComments { get; set; }
        public bool? NonNativeInvasiveSpecies { get; set; }
        public string SpeciesObserved { get; set; }
        public bool? IsHeadChanged { get; set; }
        public string HeadChangeComments { get; set; }
        public bool? IsBackwatered { get; set; }
        public string BackwaterComments { get; set; }
        public bool? IsOvertopping { get; set; }
        public string OvertoppingComments { get; set; }
        public bool? IsSubstrateEntireLength { get; set; }
        public decimal? CalculatedPassability { get; set; }
        public decimal? DefinedPassability { get; set; }
        public string PassabilityComments { get; set; }
        public byte[] PhotoInlet { get; set; }
        public byte[] PhotoOutlet { get; set; }
        public byte[] PhotoUpstream { get; set; }
        public byte[] PhotoDownstream { get; set; }
        public byte[] PhotoRoadApproachLeft { get; set; }
        public byte[] PhotoRoadApproachRight { get; set; }
        public List<Erosion> Erosions { get; set; }
        public List<Span> Spans { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Erosion:

```
namespace DNR.CulvertInventory.SERVICE
{
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "",
     ElementName = "Erosion",
     DataType = "string",
     IsNullable = true)]
    public class Erosion : BOBase
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int SurveyID { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public decimal? Length { get; set; }
        public decimal? Width { get; set; }
        public decimal? Depth { get; set; }
        public bool? IsReachingStream { get; set; }
        public string MaterialEroded { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Span:

```
namespace DNR.CulvertInventory.SERVICE
{
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "",
     ElementName = "Span",
     DataType = "string",
     IsNullable = true)]
    public class Span
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int SurveyID { get; set; }
        public short? SpanNumber { get; set; }
        public decimal? Length { get; set; }
        public decimal? Width { get; set; }
        public decimal? Height { get; set; }
        public string Material { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the method I am using to deserialize the xml:

```
public static T GetObjectFromXMLString<T>(string xml) where T: new()
        {
            T myObject = new T();

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(myObject.GetType());

            StringReader stream = new StringReader(xml); // read xml data
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);  // create reader

            object deserialized = serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            myObject = (T)deserialized;

            return myObject;
        }
```

And here is the code where I call it:

```
                command.Connection.Open();
                using (XmlReader reader = command.ExecuteXmlReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string s = reader.ReadOuterXml();
                        // do something with s
                        List<T> myList = Helpers.GetObjectFromXMLString<List<T>>(s);
                        BOList = myList;
                    }
                }
```

When I attempt to execute this, I get the following error:

```
"<Surveys xmlns=''> was not expected."
```

What am I doing wrong?  I assume it is something with the namespacing, and I have tried changing the namespace to "", removing the namespace attribute completely from the "XmlRoot" attribute, and also completely removing the "XmlRoot" attribute.  But none of that is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not related with namespaces. The root tag in your xml is `Surveys`

So just replace

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(myObject.GetType());
```

with

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(myObject.GetType(), 
                                                 new XmlRootAttribute("Surveys"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace="",...
```

Because your file does not contain `namespace` : `xmlns` does not exist

Comment: Ya.. I already tried this, and I get the same error.  I removed the "Namespace" portion of the XmlRoot attribute, and kept the remaining items, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @Amanda You don't have just one, you have on Span , Erosion and Survey

Comment: Yup.. I removed it from each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to pass in a namespace via:

```
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "");
```

perhaps this will also work:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, false) };
```

I have always used this to serialize my class to string, not deserialize it back to an object so YMMV.

--Edit --

Can you try:

```
namespace DNR.CulvertInventory.SERVICE
{
    [XmlRoot("Span")]
    public class Span
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int SurveyID { get; set; }
        public string Material { get; set; }
    }
}
```

See if that will deserialize back properly. If it does start adding your L,W,H and then tack on extra attributes until it all works, or fails. I would do this class by class to see if it works, or which class is failing.

Comment: Ya.. I have something similar to this in my serialization method, but I can't seem to figure out how to apply it to the deserialization.  There doesn't seem to be a constructor for the XmlTextReader nor the XmlSerializer that takes an argument of type XmlWriterSettings.

Comment: @AmandaMyer I added an edit, I am sure you have tried it, but just in case you havn't